# Need to install thirdparty software before my setup.exe installs in VS 2010

Tags: c#, window, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have created setup.exe for my project. But i need to add custom action where-in it checks if  given thirdparty software is installed or not. If not install; proceed with installation of thirdparty software then install my project setup. How do i do it quickly.

C# is used as coding langauge and on Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the Bootstrap Manifest Generator tool. It's way for you to add your own search and install of prerequisites beyond just the ones that Visual Studio setups supply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InstallShield. It will let you customize your installation, check for third-party dependencies etc.

http://www.installshield.com/

Comment: need do without using installsheild

Comment: Well then try to find something that is free? like http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php